# CMake: string( REGEX MATCHALL ... )

Tags: regex, cmake

I wanted to extract the part after text._ until the ending braces in cmake string(REGEX MATCHALL, i tried to match with below pattern, but i couldn't manage last part, it is matching everything rather end at ).

```
variableX is file(READ "myfilepath" variableX)
string(REGEX MATCHALL "_Z.*\\)$" result ${variableX})
```

also tried

```
 string(REGEX MATCHALL "_Z.*\)$" result ${variableX})
```

variableX

```
- Name: EXTRAM_CODE_SECTION
  Attributes: |
    FIXED
  Content: |
    * (.text._ZN6Module16bwcL1CCScheduler12CSfScheduler14dlTimerHandlerEjs)
    * (.text._ZN18CLteMsgHandlerTask18findAndCallHandlerEP18bwcCommonMsgHeader)
    * (.text._ZN6Module15bwcL1CCInfoBase13CSubFrameInfo15updateGapStatusEv)
    * (.text._ZN6ltephy4l1cc7CUlHarq13storeDCIGrantERKNS0_9CCellTimeEPK10bwcUlGrantjPbS8_PKjNS0_13l1ccCellIndexE)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I guess you use `${variableX}` as the last argument, not just `variableX`. Am I right?

Comment: true, i used ${variableX}

Comment: not sure if we have efficient, but i got through it with string(REGEX MATCHALL "[^_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*[^\\)]